# Java JSpinner Looks Ugly

Tags: java, jspinner

[GUI](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/5389/spinl.jpg)

i am trying to use JSpinner but as you can see from the attached image that it looks bad.

i am on windows 7. i was wondering if anyone knows how to make it look good?

just for clarity. bad means the edges dont line up and good means the spin control edges line up correctly.

thank you.

EDIT: maybe there is no cure for this? because i checked [site](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingaJSpinnerLookandFeel.htm) and all their examples look like this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a different Look & Feel, although it looks like right now you are going for the platform look and feel.  Some alternatives (that won't, as far as I know, mimic the Windows 7 look at feel) are [Substance](https://substance.dev.java.net/) and [Nimbus](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/nimbus_laf.html).

Comment: they look great! i was wondering the learning curve? im a beginner and after i have done my gui stuff i still have to code the model of my app... just a rough idea will do. thanks again.

Comment: Nimbus is working just by putting in the code on the webpage you provided! looks sweetttttttttttttttttt!

Comment: question: does Nimbus implement something like this? a textfield with a limit on characters it holds? eg. text field can contain only 10 chars and after that it stops taking input.

Comment: @ikurtz - Nimbus is just a look and feel.  Your spinner will do whatever your spinner is programmed to do.  Consider asking a second SO question (and perhaps before that, doing a google search) on JTextFields with limits (yes, it's possible)

Comment: yes i have seen the implementations of it but was wondering if you knew any other methods so wicked as nimbus :)

Comment: @ikurtz - if you're curious on what nimbus covers, search around for documentation on what a Java Look & Feel does.  There's a lot out there.